# Find MS SQL Server column information for Django models

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models

I have done this before but can't remember how, so forgive me if this has already been answered.

I want to create a model in Django from an MS SQL Server table. How would I find the relevant information for the columns? I used the command line to retrieve this information. An example of what I am looking for:

```
region = models.CharField(db_column='Region', max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Comment: Is `inspectdb` what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Comment: That's it! Such a simple solution  

If you post this as the answer, I'll accept it!